# Test for something in a string and then bolden it in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this string in a variable

```
var stringName = "There is the word cupcake in this string"
```

Acknowledging that the `.bold()` function makes a string bolden, how can I test that "cupcake" is in the string, and then apply `.bold()` whenever and wherever it is? I was thinking something like this:

```
if (stringName.indexOf("cupcake") !== -1) {
    stringName.substring(
        stringName.indexOf("cupcake"), 
        stringName.indexOf("cupcake")+"cupcake".length
    ).bold();
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Let me clear up some questions. So, I'm storing the string in an array inside an array inside an object because I have many strings to show on the webpage. I've set up a specific `<div>` to with an ID where I want the text to show. Each string inside of the nested array is added as a list tag to the inner HTML of the div. That's how the string is displayed as a text. I've tried each of your methods, but none seem to work.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code for asimes' suggestion:

```
var infoShowingOnScreen = document.getElementById("infoShowing");
for (var i = 0; i < sectionArrays.publications[0].length; i++) {
    if (sectionArrays.publications[0][i].indexOf("cupcake") !== -1) {
        sectionArrays.publications[0][i] = sectionArrays.publications[0][i].replace(new RegExp("cupcake", "g"), "<b>cupcake</b>");
    }
    infoShowingOnScreen.innerHTML += "<li>" + sectionArrays.publications[0][i].toString() + "</li>";
}
```

`sectionArrays` is the object, publications is the array, and the code is accessing every element of the first element of that array. Each of those are strings.

Comment: What does "does not work" exactly mean?

Comment: `substring` returns a new string. You should store the returned/new value. Also note that [`String.prototype.bold`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold#wikiArticle) has been _deprecated_.

Comment: @zerkms "does not work" means that the text does not get bold. The website runs, though.

Comment: @Vohuman Oh, hmm. I didn't know. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @ZodiacZubeda what "text"? In your example it's just a string. How is it supposed to "get bold" if you don't put it anywhere on a page?

Comment: @zerkms I'm displaying on a webpage.

Comment: @ZodiacZubeda in this code - you don't. You generated a string then threw it away.

Comment: In the first code that you posted you never reassign `stringName`, you just generate a new string if the condition is true and that new string is **not** assigned to `stringName`. It should have been `stringName = stringName.substring(...).bold();`. I suspect that something similar is happening with your usage of the code we posted. In my own answer, `result` is assigned what you want to store

Comment: @asimes I made it so, using `stringName` as a reference, `stringName = stringName.replace(new RegExp("cupcake", "g"), "<b>cupcake</b>");`. Would that work?

Comment: @ZodiacZubeda, It seems like that would solve your problem but I am just guessing, can't really say without seeing all of the code

Comment: @asimes You see, I would be more than happy to show you the code, but its kinda confidential in its current stage.

Comment: @asimes Have you seen the update in my original question?

Comment: @ZodiacZubeda, Yes I did, that doesn't help though. The point is that the code several of us posted works and that you are not using it correctly somehow. That is why I asked you to post what you tried

Comment: @asimes Alright, I added some of the code I used for your suggestion, leaving out my code unnecessary for this situation. In the actual code, I don't actually use "cupcake", rather a certain name, but that shouldn't make a difference, I imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace` and pass in a `new RegExp` to replace all occurrences of `"cupcake"`:

```
var str = "There is the word cupcake in this string. Another cupcake word. For good measure, cupcake";
var result = str.replace(new RegExp("cupcake", "g"), "<b>cupcake</b>");
console.log(result);
```

Note that `bold` just returns a string with `"<b>"` and `"</b>"` around it. The output of the above code is:

```
"There is the word <b>cupcake</b> in this string. Another <b>cupcake</b> word. For good measure, <b>cupcake</b>"
```

**Edit**: I have posted a complete HTML / JavaScript example with a screen shot to show that this does indeed work. The problem you are facing must be elsewhere in your code

**Complete code example**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="infoShowing"></ul>
    <script>
        var sectionArrays = {};
        sectionArrays.publications = [[
            "foo cupcake bar",
            "foo",
            "foo cupcake cupcake bar cupcake baz",
        ]];

        var infoShowingOnScreen = document.getElementById("infoShowing");
        for (var i = 0; i < sectionArrays.publications[0].length; i++) {
            // No need for this check
            //if (sectionArrays.publications[0][i].indexOf("cupcake") !== -1) {
                sectionArrays.publications[0][i] = sectionArrays.publications[0][i].replace(new RegExp("cupcake", "g"), "<b>cupcake</b>");
            //}

            // No need for toString(), sectionArrays.publications[0][i] is already a string
            infoShowingOnScreen.innerHTML += "<li>" + sectionArrays.publications[0][i] + "</li>";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: cupcake]

Comment: I did not downvote but why use `new RegExp("cupcake", "g")` just basic `str.replace("cupcake", <b>cupcake</b>");` would work as well

Comment: @GRC, that will only replace the first occurrence of `"cupcake"`, not all of them

Comment: @asimes you can use `str.replace("cupcake", "<b>cupcake</b>", "g");` or even `str.replace(/cupcake/g, "<b>cupcake</b>");`

Comment: @ZodiacZubeda, Maybe update your question to post what you tried so we can see

Comment: @ZodiacZubeda they do work, it's you who don't use the results.

Comment: @ZodiacZubeda, Added a complete example, HTML and all

Comment: @asimes It works! I can't believe it! Maybe it was the if statement. Thanks so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

`.bold()` is deprecated, you can write a quick and easy replacement using:

```
str.replace(/(cupcake)/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

This will find all occurrences of cupcake, then add bold tags around it

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold) `bold()` is deprecated. All it does is wrap a string in `<b>` tags so it's easy enough to create a function to do that without having to use `bold()`. Try this

```
function makeWordBold(string, target){

  // regex finds all occurences of target within string
  var regex       = new RegExp(target, 'g'),
      targetBold  = '<b>' + target + '</b>';

      // replace all occurences with text wrapped in bold tags
  return  string.replace(regex, targetBold);
}

var string      = 'foo cupcake bar cupcake baz.',
    target      = 'cupcake',
    boldString  = makeWordBold(string, target);

console.log(boldString); //  foo <b>cupcake</b> bar <b>cupcake</b> baz.
```